# Alternative to Javascript alert in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I didn't want to have to ask a new question so I looked around everywhere, but I can't seem to find a solution to my question. So basically, I want to find an alternative way to prompt a user with a message box on a certain condition. Currently, I have a working form written in a PHP file and it forces the user to enter a valid email address. If they fail to do so, an alert box comes up telling them to do so. This is all fine and works well, but I wanted to get a nicer looking, styled alert box. I read about using Jquery but even using that, I haven't been able to do it. I think I may have done something wrong, mind you. But still, here's the current code I have:

```
    if ($mailcheck==FALSE)
  {
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Please enter a valid email address!");
  window.location.href="../index";
  </script>';
  }
else
  {
  $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
  $subject = $_POST["subject"];
  $message = $_POST["message"];
```

Where I have the Javascript Alert box, how can I replace it with a custom box? Sorry if my question seems a little poorly worded.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Try using [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)!

Comment: Google the term "Modal"

Comment: [alertify.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)

Comment: You can't use CSS with a Javascript alert box, I guess what I'm really looking for is an alternative way to make an alert box, however one that supports CSS :)

Comment: Ah, thanks for all the comments, guys, I will try some now :)

Comment: @user3321156 do you want the login page or what ever to send the data to a processing script and then redirect back to the page with the error <b>OR</b> do you want the page to send the data to the server and return with the error but with out any sort of redirect?

Comment: It's a script that I inserted into my index.php page. The script is basically an email form and has multiple outcomes based on user input. At current, if a user does not enter a valid email address, an alert box pops up saying to enter a valid email address, then redirects the page back to index.php. I don't want to use an alert box if possible, as I'd rather have my own custom style of box. People say I should create one with Jquery, but I don't know how to insert that into the PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most comfortable way is to use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/). But you can also make your own one with HTML/CSS and some JavaScript.

**EDIT**: Here is an example of using jQueryUI dialog box:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the link I have sent (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) press "view source", it will show you an example with clear code. For all the examples and properties, you can check this link: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/. As you can see it supports several options to customize your own box. I hope it can help, if you are stucked, feel free to ask.

Comment: Well first, I'm not here for the votes, but to help. On the other hand, I have tried inserting HTML code but I failed, I needed time to find out how to do it properly. Now finally I got it work.